# Script that reads PDF metadata and writes to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a script to read PDF metadata to ease a task at work.  The current working version is not very usable in the long run:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

BASEDIR = ''
PDFFiles = []
def extractor():
    output = open('windoutput.txt', 'r+')
    for file in PDFFiles:
        try:
            pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(open(BASEDIR + file, 'r'))
            pdf_info = pdf_toread.getDocumentInfo()

            #print str(pdf_info)   #print full metadata if you want

            x = file + "~" + pdf_info['/Title'] + " ~ " + pdf_info['/Subject']
            print x
                output.write(x + '\n')
            except:
                x = file + '~' + ' ERROR: Data missing or corrupt'
                print x
                output.write(x + '\n')
                pass
    output.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    extractor()
```

Currently, as you can see, I have to manually input the working directory and manually populate the list of PDF files.  It also just prints out the data in the terminal in a format that I can copy/paste/separate into a spreadsheet.

I'd like the script to work automatically in whichever directory I throw it in and populate a CSV file for easier use.  So far:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader
import csv
import os

def extractor():
    basedir = os.getcwd()
    extension = '.pdf'
    pdffiles = [filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.pdf'), os.listdir(basedir))]

    with open('pdfmetadata.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        for f in pdffiles:
            try:
                pdf_to_read = PdfFileReader(open(f, 'r'))
                pdf_info = pdf_to_read.getDocumentInfo()
                title = pdf_info['/Title']
                subject = pdf_info['/Subject']
                csvfile.writerow([file, title, subject])
                print 'Metadata for %s written successfully.' % (f)
            except:
                print 'ERROR reading file %s.' % (f)
                #output.writerow(x + '\n')
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    extractor()
```

In its current state it seems to just prints a single error (as in, the error message in the exception, not an error returned by Python) message and then stop.  I've been staring at it for a while and I'm not really sure where to go from here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo or not, but the last line is not indented properly in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The script I used to download the files was saving the files with '\r\n' trailing after the file name, which I didn't notice until I actually `ls`'d the directory to see what was up.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

1. `writerow([file, title, subject])` should be `writerow([f, title, subject])`
2. You can use `sys.exc_info()` to print the details of your error

   - http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

Comment: Figured it out.  The script was saving the files with '\r\n' trailing after the filename, which I didn't notice until I actually `ls`'d the directory to see what was up.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the pdffiles variable contains what you think it does?  I was getting a list inside a list... so maybe try:

```
for files in pdffiles:
    for f in files:
        #do stuff with f
```

I personally like glob.  Notice I add * before the .pdf in the extension variable:

```
import os
import glob

basedir = os.getcwd()
extension = '*.pdf'

pdffiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(basedir,extension)))
```